# Почему ?.Invoke() считается потокобезопасным с делегатами?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, делегаты

Как [написано](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators?redirectedfrom=MSDN#thread-safe-delegate-invocation) в документации, PropertyChanged?.Invoke() превращается в

```
var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
if (handler != null)
{
    handler(…);
}
```

Что мешает другому треду в момент между успешной проверкой (handler != null) и запуском handler'а сделать

```
handler -= PropertyChanged;
```

и получить NullReferenceException? Почему это считается thread-safe?

Comment: у другого потока нет доступа к локальной переменной `handler` - поэтому и изменить ее он не может

Comment: @Grundy путаете. handler - это не локальная переменная. Приведённый фрагмент - это описание реализации конструкции `?.Invoke()`, то есть то, как это выглядит на CIL.

Comment: @rotabor, сути это не меняет.

Comment: @Grundy универсальный аргумент, нужно запомнить. Главное, получить тот же результат, а каким путём он получен - не важно, сути это не меняет.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведённый фрагмент - это описание реализации конструкции `?.Invoke()`, то есть то, как это выглядит на CIL. То есть нигде в коде не существует переменной `handler`.

После того, как мы получили указатель (он ложится на стек), манипуляции с делегатом где-либо уже не предотвратят вызов метода по этому указателю. Строго говоря, операция дублирования значения на стеке аналогична созданию локальной переменной, поэтому код вполне отвечает реализации.

Вот пример, который показывает, как это работает:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
static class Programm {
    class A {
        int _p;
        public Action PropertyChanged;
        public int Psafe {
            get { return _p; }
            set {
                _p = value;
                Task.Run(() => {
                    var handler = PropertyChanged;
                    if (handler != null) {
                        Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
                        Console.WriteLine(handler.Equals(PropertyChanged));  // false
                        // показывает, что PropertyChanged уже не тот,
                        // который в handler 
                        handler();
                        Console.WriteLine(_p);
                    }
                });
            }
        }           
        public int Punsafe {
            get { return _p; }
            set {
                _p = value;
                Task.Run(() => {
                    // это нерекомендуемый вариант
                    if (PropertyChanged != null) {
                        Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
                        try { PropertyChanged(); }
                        catch { Console.WriteLine("Error occured"); }
                        Console.WriteLine(_p);
                    }
                });
            }
        }           
    }
    static void B() {
        Console.WriteLine("Method B");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        Console.WriteLine("Safe test");
        a.PropertyChanged += B;
        a.Psafe = 3;
        Console.WriteLine("Property set to 3");
        Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        a.PropertyChanged -= B;
        Console.WriteLine("Main 1");
        Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Main 2");
        Console.WriteLine("Unsafe test");
        a.PropertyChanged += B;
        a.Punsafe = 5;
        Console.WriteLine("Property set to 5");
        Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        a.PropertyChanged -= B;
        Console.WriteLine("Main 3");
        Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Main 4");
    }
}

-->

Safe test
Property set to 3
Main 1
Method B
3
Main 2
Unsafe test
Property set to 5
Main 3
Error occured
5
Main 4
```

`?.` - это просто упрощённая проверка на null при доступе к члену класса, синтаксический сахар. А документация объясняет, что реализован этот оператор потокобезопасным способом, что работает как при вызове делегатов, так и вообще при доступе к любому члену: "The ?. operator evaluates its left-hand operand no more than once, guaranteeing that it cannot be changed to null after being verified as non-null" (над текстом по ссылке в начале вопроса).

**P. S.** В данном примере вместо `Task.Delay(...).Wait()` можно использовать `Thread.Sleep(...)` (но нет необходимости), но при работе в однопоточном окружении (STA - Single Threaded Apartment, как пример - WinForms) `Thread.Sleep(...)` будет полность блокировать единственный поток выполнения формы (никакие события обрабатываться не будут), поэтому используйте `await Task.Delay(...)` (о возможных конфликтах придётся позаботиться явно).

Попутно выяснилась одна интересная особенность. Делегат с его списком вызова не похож на обычный список, который может существовать пустым. Если у делегата нет ни одного подписчика, то его значение null.

Comment: в справке речь не про Invoke, а про потокобезопасность оператора `?.`, так что это скорее у тебя все в кучу смешалось ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Я понял, что handler - это некая одноразовая локальная переменная, создаваемая во время компиляции, которую из кода не видно. В случае, если бы это были не делегаты, а другие ссылочные типы, то тогда всё ещё можно было бы всё сломать, назначив null тому на что они ссылаются. Но с делегатами такое не работает, ибо они ссылаются на методы, которые не могут быть null. А значит либо в handler'е останется ссылка на этот метод, либо вредоносный тред сотрёт PropertyChanged до проверки на null и в результате у нас всё равно не получится исключения.

Comment: @Grundy Это было такое первое восприятие вопроса.

Comment: Task.Delay.Wait - грязный код. Вообще sync-over-async это жуть, по cути. Научитесь для синхронного ожидания использовать Thread.Sleep.

Comment: @aepot результат тот же самый, как говорится, сути не меняет.

Comment: @rotabor да не тот же. Нагрузка на пул потоков, дополнительные задержки. Можно ещё 2 миллиона итераций в пустом цикле крутить, тоже будет задержка с тем же результатом. Если вам плевать, то хотя-бы новичкам старайтесь показывать вменяемый код.

Comment: @aepot в данном примере смысла менять шило на мыло нет. В других случаях - да. Но, боюсь, в случае STA `Thread.Sleep` заблокирует весь поток, не давая обрабатывать другие события.

Comment: Task.Run плевать хотел на STA, он спавнит поток безусловно. Иначе как бы он работал в UI приложениях типа Winforms или WPF?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149529/discussion-between-rotabor-and-aepot).

Comment: _однопоточном окружении (STA) Thread.Sleep(...) будет полность блокировать единственный поток_ - он в любом окружении будет блокировать поток. Просто он не выполняет дополнительной работы, расчитанной на асинхронность как Task.Delay. То есть вы сначала запусаете мощную асинхронную машину ожидания, а потом блочите поток через Wait. Смысла в этом нет вообще никакого, такой код не стоит писать вообще.